# Distribute C# DLLs including install COM-object

Tags: c#, com, software-distribution, regasm

I have a **C# with .NET 4.71** project and created a **COM object** with reference to another project. 
So by just creating the project with release configuration gives me some DLLs within the release folder and automatically installed the com object on my development computer.

For other computers, I have to **copy all the files** and **execute regasm to install the COM object**. So, the problem is, that this is *too much work* doing manually for many computers.

So how can I **distribute those files and install the com object easily**? Also updating them should work. It must be a **silent installer**.

Comment: make an installer or if this is for the workplace just use CI/CD and use automated deployments

Comment: What kind of installer is the best for this approach? So do you mean, I can use Azure DevOps to deploy to 100 user computers and automatically install the com object on their computer?

Comment: The one that suits all your business's and team's needs.  There's plenty of stuff out there

Comment: A library exposed through COM always requires an installer.  It can't be "silent", since it writes HKLM registry keys it requires UAC elevation.

Comment: If everything is in the same directory and the only EXE that needs to run it is in that directory, then you don't need to register it. You can use Isolated COM. For the .NET assembly, you want to use mt.exe to generate a manifest for the assembly. Then for the EXE, you can add a manifest dependency to the .NET assembly.